# Как использовать react-snap с динамически меняющимися данными?

Tags: reactjs, seo

Пишу на React с использование react-snap. Мне необходимо реализовать SEO оптимизацию, все данные для seo берутся с сервера.

При формирование путей(react-route) я использую язык, который берется динамически с сервера.

```
`/${lang}` 
`/${lang}/articles`
`/${lang}/articles/${slug}`
```

И так далее.
Мета теги я указываю с помощью Helmet. Данные для мета тегов беру с сервера.

```
<Helmet>
    <title>{items.title}</title>
    <meta name="description" content={items.description} />
    <meta name="Keywords" content={items.keywords}/>
</Helmet>
```

После билда папка build выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внутри undefined

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Папку он назван undefined, потому что не видит язык. Если я указываю язык статически, т.е.

```
`/ru`
`/ru/articles`
```

То после билда, вместо папки undefined - папка ru

Вопрос.
Как сделать seo оптимизацию с динамически изменяющимися данными?
Почему он не видит язык?
И для детальной страницы статьи не создается копия при билде.

Что можно использовать для seo оптимизации?